# Can't see window size in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

I'm using Chrome developer tools for version  49.0.2623.110 m and I notice that the little box displaying the window WIDTHxHEIGHT when you resize is now gone or moved. Am I just not seeing it? Is it moved?

I use Viewport Resizer now but I really missed having both options to check window size...

Comment: Got the same problem here

Comment: features backs in v50

Comment: yep, noticed. glad it was just a bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for answers to this problem myself, and I found a couple of pages. Apparently, it's a bug in Chrome v49, that should be fixed in Chrome 50. Here are a couple of links to the discussions:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/LhOfBFSBdx8

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=582421