# Chrome: get actual viewport size on the screen

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome 47, whenever I change the viewport size using the webinspenctor separator, the new size have beeing showed in the top-right corner of the viewport. From 48 version this very useful freature is no more available.

Anyone know how to bring it back?

Comment: Duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36478296/cant-see-window-size-in-chrome

Comment: feature backs in v50